# C# SQL - Insert into External DB server

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a got a app with sql. But i have sql database on VPS. What I must write to connection?

```
new SqlConnection(@"Data source=server_ip;Trusted_Connection=yes;Database=NameOfDatabse;User Id=Username;Password=MyPassword;server=server_ip");
```

I try this code, but it doesn't works. Thanks for help, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: mysql OR sql-server. not both.

Comment: Ok, i must use MySQL, no SQLserver ?

Comment: You need to decide which you are going to use before you can write code to connect to it.

Comment: The connection seems legit. Have you checked the server status? Is it online? Is it reachable? What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: You have `Trusted_Connection=yes`, but also specify username and password. Choose one, not both.

Comment: I want to use MySQL, error is SqlException was unhandled.

Comment: use http://www.connectionstrings.com/ to figure out which connection string you need

Comment: @Expertik post the full exception message, including the inner exception (if any).

Comment: When establishing a connection to SQL Server error occurred A network-related or instance. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (Provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server.) 

and error is for sqlConn.Open();

Comment: check that the database server you have specified is correct and exists.

Comment: Trusted_Connection means you want to login with windows authentication .In that case you need t oremove username and password - its irrelevant.Im not sure how this work for mySQL , i think you need some plugin.

Comment: Do you know that MySql and Sql Server are two different products? The classes to use for Sql Server are not the same classes used for MySql. You say that you want to use MySql but you use the classes for Sql Server. No wonder that they don't work.